# Renumbering figure in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, tex, pdflatex, typesetting

How can I make figures be renumbered in a TeX document?  I want the main figures to be 1, 2, 3, ...etc.  But then I want a section to have supplementary figures, S1, S2, S3, S4.  The "S" does not have to appear in the figure name, but I do want to reset the counter.

Comment: This would be better asked on the TeX/LaTeX Stack Exchange site, now in public beta: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: have you looked at the caption package?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41318/how-to-change-table-numbering-scheme-at-a-new-section and http://bytesizebio.net/2013/03/11/adding-supplementary-tables-and-figures-in-latex/ for more information and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39315/how-to-change-the-numbering-for-different-figures and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85776/change-figure-numbering-for-appendix?rq=1 for more info

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Next to reseting the counter for the figures:

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}
```

You can also add the "S" by using:

```
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\@arabic\c@figure}
\makeatother
```

Comment: You should always use `\makeatother` after this or it will mess up the use of @ in commands.

Comment: Works for subfigures too: `\setcounter{subfigure}{0}`.

Comment: For being able to restore the original behaviour: `\let\originalthefigure\thefigure` before this, and `\let\thefigure\originalthefigure` when you want to restore it

Answer (score 11):

you can reset the figure counter with

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}
```